# how to stop listening to a port

Tags: c++, sockets, postgresql, port, ace

I have a linux application written in c++.
The application listens to a socket on a certain port. I implemented this using ACE Acceptor.
In addition the application starts postgresql database using the init script /etc/init.d/postgresql start by calling the ACE_OS::system function.

The problem I am having is: When the application exits, the port is still occupied. When I run netstat I see that the postgres is listening to that port. (This only happens if I start postgres from the application on any given port).

Is there a way to close the port? Why does postgres listen to that port?

Comment: Isn't it your question actually how to stop postgres?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, not necessarily.  The app might be a command/response server which, as one of its actions, starts up the system's database.  What this suggests (running as root, leaking resources to child processes, etc.) is something else. :)

Comment: But it says "I see postgres is listening to that port" ?

Comment: Yes, because postgres has inherited the socket that the OP's app opened.  If the app also opened `/dev/null` and made a `pipe()` before starting postgres, `lsof` would show that the descendant postgres was holding `/dev/null` and a `pipe()`, too.

Comment: Ugh, I hope this is some system-management app, because otherwise starting postgres in your app sounds very wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to close the port?

Yes.  Close the socket, or set FD_CLOEXEC on the underlying file descriptor.

Or ... wrap your call to the child process (`...postgresql start`) with something that will close fds higher than stderr:

```
ACE_OS::system("perl -MPOSIX -e 'POSIX::close($_) for 3 .. sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX); exec @ARGV' /etc/init.d/postgresql start");
```

or similar.  Tuck that in a script to make it look nicer.

> Why does postgres listen to that port?

Your child processes (and their children) are inheriting your open file descriptors, including the socket your c++ app opens.

Comment: Is there a way to start the child process in a way that wont inherit the open file descriptor?

Comment: @Shay, yes.  Either close the descriptor before exec'ing the child (close(the_right_fd) or FD_CLOEXEC) or loop through the fd table as the perl snippet does and hope for the best.